# Expo URI starting with ph:// causes MediaLibrary Error: Could not get the file's extension

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

In my React Native Expo app running on an iOS phone, I am trying to download an image from a URL and save it to the phone's photo album.

Downloading the photo using

```
    const { uri: localUri } = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      url,
      imageLocalPath
    );
```

got me the `localUri` value:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8DE8ED8-1F21-49CD-C44E-FE519FE5414D/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540gameveloster%252Ftest/photo_0.png
```

The problem comes when creating a `MediaLibrary` asset so it can be saved to the library.

```
const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(localUri);
await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(asset.uri);
```

The URI of photos returned by `MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(localUri)` is one that starts with `ph://`, such as `ph://D2A0552A-1C8F-4067-A36E-E9154F530694` for the asset:

```
{
   "creationTime":1683673252037,
   "duration":0,
   "filename":"IMG_1234.PNG",
   "height":512,
   "id":"D2A0552A-1C8F-4067-A36E-E9154F530694/L0/001",
   "mediaSubtypes":[
      
   ],
   "mediaType":"photo",
   "modificationTime":1683673255526,
   "uri":"ph://D2A0552A-1C8F-4067-A36E-E9154F530694",
   "width":512
}
```

This causes `MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync` to fail with the error

> Error: Could not get the file's extension.

Is there another way to work around this problem?

Thanks!